# runOnUiThread not working on Fragment - Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have this method

```
public void contStart(View view) {
        Log.d("Enter", "Here");

        //setLabels();

        this.runOnUiThread(() -> {
            //startButton =  view.findViewById(R.id.start);
            this.startButton.setText("...");
            this.startButton.setEnabled(false);
            //connButton.setEnabled(false);
        });
        synchronized (lock) {
            contSet = true;
        }
        doConnect();
    }
```

But the instruction `this.startButton.setText("...");` and all inside the runOnUiThread are not working. It also does not throw any errors.

`startButton` is in a Fragment, and the method is in the "general" class, not in the fragment class.

If I active the line `startButton =  view.findViewById(R.id.start);` it works. But in other parts of the class, I don't have the view argument.

At the beggining of the class I have this.

```
View inflatedView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.tabmain, null);
startButton = inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.start);
```

I think it is an error of not understanding well the views in the Fragments.

Comment: And will `runOnUiThread` be called? I mean if you add a log in it, will it print the log in logcat?

Comment: You can get the your `inflatedView` anywhere in the `Fragment` by calling `getView()`. But what you're doing now is good, you really should use `startButton = view.findViewById(R.id.start);`, if you're going to use `startButton` somewhere in the `Fragment`.

Comment: Yes,"Enter Here" is Logging. All the code is working perfectly but not the runOnUiThread. Only these parts.

Comment: @IsraeldelaCruz Ok, and how I call that button for example in a external loop in other point. Or in other way, how I get the view that I want when I can't access it by argument

Comment: You can get the view that you want by using `getView().findViewById(R.id.my_view)`. Inside the `Fragment` or if you have a reference to the `Fragment`. If you can't access the `Fragment` then you shouldn't be calling the `View`